# F#: Cannot call stored procedure on MariaDB database using SQLProvider

Tags: sql, f#, mariadb, type-providers

I adapted my code from the instructions [here](http://fsprojects.github.io/SQLProvider/core/programmability.html).

```
open FSharp.Data.Sql

let [<Literal>] connection_str = "Server=localhost;Port=3306;SSL Mode=None;Uid=<UID>;Pwd=<PWD>;Database=<DB>"
type provider = SqlDataProvider<Common.DatabaseProviderTypes.MYSQL, connection_str>
let context = provider.GetDataContext()

context.Procedures.SpGetFrontContracts.Invoke(1)
```

Intellisense works until the period after SpGetFrontContracts. After that, nothing. Trying to compile, I get:

```
Error   FS0039  The field, constructor or member 'Invoke' is not defined.
```

I am otherwise able to connect to the database and insert and query data, as long as I stick to tables and views.

SpGetFrontContracts is a valid stored procedure in my database (its actual name is sp_get_front_contracts, but the type provider seems to remove underscores). I can run it successfully using HeidiSQL. In case it's useful, here's the create code:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`<UID>`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_get_front_contracts`(
    IN `Group` INT
)
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT ''
BEGIN
    SELECT p.DateTime, p.Contract, p.Volume, c.Name
    FROM tbl_contract_price_data p
    INNER JOIN tbl_contracts c on p.Contract = c.ID
    WHERE c.`Group` = `Group`
    ORDER BY p.DateTime
    LIMIT 1000;
END
```

I tried creating a simpler sproc that was named 'test', took no parameters, and simply ran a select statement. It showed up in the type provider under Procedures, but again I could not call `Invoke` on it.

My best guess is that `Invoke` is being inherited from some namespace or assembly reference I don't have, so I'm currently looking through the [SqlProvider source](https://github.com/fsprojects/SQLProvider) to try to figure out what it might be. I'm currently referencing:

- FSharp.Core
- FSharp.Data
- FSharp.Data.SqlProvider
- mscorlib
- System
- System.Core
- System.Data
- System.Numerics
- System.ValueTyple
- System.Xml.Linq

Thank you for any suggestions.

Edit: It looks like the action is in [SqlDesignTime.fs](https://github.com/fsprojects/SQLProvider/blob/master/src/SQLProvider/SqlDesignTime.fs) in a function called generateSprocMethod that starts on line 346. I'll try to figure out what's going on in there.

Edit: After three days banging my head against this, I gave up and just used [MySQL Connector/NET](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/).

Comment: What's the type of `context.Procedures.SpGetFrontContracts`?

Comment: Mousing over it, I see:

property SqlDataProvider<...>.dataContext.Procedures.SpGetFrontContracts: SqlDataProvider<...>.dataContext.Procedures.SpGetFrontContracts.Result.

Comment: The `Result` type appears to be created on line 352 of [SqlDesignTime.fs](https://github.com/fsprojects/SQLProvider/blob/master/src/SQLProvider/SqlDesignTime.fs).

Comment: It appears `Invoke` is added to the `Result` type on lines 357-412, in particular see line 402. I'm not familiar with creating type providers or writing code that runs at design time instead of run time, so I'm out of my depth here. I'm going to see if I can get into the generateSprocMethod with the debugger today (or just have it pop up message boxes if it comes to that). My guess is, something is going wrong in there before the `Invoke` method can be added to the `Result` type.

Comment: What version of SQLProvider are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your underlying data or structures, but I know these are two other (correct) ways to solve it:

```
WHERE c.`Group` =   `Group`  -- what you have.

-- possible corrections:
WHERE c.`Group` = p.`Group`  -- did you mean this?
WHERE c.`Group` =   "Group"  -- or this?
```